# json file with emoji triggering error on build "found invalid Unicode character escape code while parsing a quoted scalar at line x column y"

Tags: ruby, unicode, jekyll

I'm stuck on a Jekyll build error. I'm trying to read an Instagram json feed that's placed in my site's `_data` directory. When it saves, my watch task kicks off this error:

```
Regenerating: 2 file(s) changed at 2016-09-04 08:18:40 ...error:
Error: (/app/src/jekyll/_data/instagram.json): found invalid Unicode character escape code while parsing a quoted scalar at line 394 column 25
```

The offending JSON block from `instagram.json` is:

```
    "caption": {
        "text": "this is why Mike's off picking us up McDonald's right now \ud83d\ude23",
        "id": "17849231221189210",
        "created_time": "1468191913",
        "from": {
            "full_name": "John Smith",
            "username": "john_smith",
            "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13398734_458315291028923_1826341282_a.jpg",
            "id": "5911902"
        }
    },
```

That character sequence at the end of the `text` property is the culprit (`\ud83d\ude23`)--it's an emoji.

I've tried setting the `encoding: "utf-8"` property in my `_config.yml` file but still get the same error. I also tried installing the [jemoji](https://github.com/jekyll/jemoji) plugin but, as far as I can tell, it just seems to want to replace special keywords (e.g. `:smiling:`) with `<img>` tags, and that's not what I'm looking to do here.

A Python script is handling fetching/writing the instagram.json file, so if there's some sort of preprocessing that can would output emoji characters in a way that Jekyll will want to work with it, I'm open to that as a solution as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution? I have the exact issue, I'm generating a JSON file from an Instagram API response, Jekyll was fine with it until an emoji character was included in a post description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `\ud83d\ude23` by `&#128547;` or `&#x1f623;` html entities, works well.